# multiple values from one parameter

Tags: java, parameters, applet

Quick simple question... I would like to know how I can get multiple values from one parameter in a Java applet scrolling banner.

I need my applet to display product parameters of Nokia, Ericson and Samsung.

I'm told that an Applet can only get one parameter of a particular name, so I need to work out how to get multiple values from the one 'product' parameter.

What I'm currently working with ..

```
 <param name=im0 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im1 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im2 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im3 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im4 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im5 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im6 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im7 value=" Text Here ">
 <param name=im8 value=" Text Here ">
```

Comment: *"scrolling banner"*  Probably better done as JavaScript, BTW.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson 
 Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 ways, one of which you already seem to have discovered.

- Add each part as `paramNN` where `NN` represents a number.  Keep trying new values of `NN` until a `null` is returned.
- Concatenate values using a character they will not normally contain (e.g. `,` or `|`) and split the value once received.
- Use the parameter value to specify the name of a file containing complex data.

Comment: I'd rather use the 4th way: have a separate parameter (e.g. PARAM_COUNT) denoting how many certain parameter (PARAM_n) will repeat, and get all PARAMs by all n in 0 to PARAM_COUNT-1